# What happens when the last bitcoin is mined?

Tags: mining-reward, reward-schedule

If miners are who do the bookkeeping for bitcoin, what happens when mining is no longer profitable, or there are no more coins to mine? Who does the bookkeeping?

Comment: they will be incentivized by transaction fees instead.